# unable to set negative numbers in red as default in libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice

I have just started using libreoffice calc. So I have a doubt here.

I have to display all negative numbers in red. I don't want to format each cell manually rather I would like to set this property as default but I can't see any such option. I have to format everytime I want this property.

here is the screenshot. I have option to display negative nos. in red but I can't set this as default property.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the default for a single spreadsheet, go to Styles and Formatting, then modify the *Default* cell style.

To use this setting for any new spreadsheets, go to *File → Templates → Save As Template*.  Mark the check box *Set as default template*.

This was adapted from https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/9550/in-calc-where-is-the-custom-default-formatting-setup/.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Conditional Formatting](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Conditional_Formatting)**.

[image]

Select all the cells you want and set condition like this:

[image]

All negative number will be red in few click.

Comment: this proposal doesn't not solve this issue, because he doesn't want to select cells, but to set it as default for spreadsheet.

Comment: @Redbob - Yes, you are right. But it's still better than "format each cell manually" as he writes. This can format whole document.